# Какая разница между диалоговыми и модальными окнами

Tags: терминология

Собственно не могу понять, есть ли какая нибудь разница? Или это одно и тоже?

В [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#vertically-centered) классы элемента модалки вот такие `modal-dialog`.

---

Я думал `Dialog` - то что выводится по центру

А `Modal` прилипает к границам вьюпорта

Comment: В UI модальный диалог не дает взаимодействовать с другими компонентами пока он открыт. А немодальных диалогов может быть несколько одновременно открыто и с ними можно взаимодействовать как и с другими компононентами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Терминологически от просто диалогового окна можно отказаться (от диалога в нём). От модального - нет. Например:
https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-modal-and-dialog
Но если быть совсем точным, то под dialog подразумевают немодальный диалог, а под modal - модальный диалог.